# Выборка значений из БД по интервалу времени вводимого пользователем. Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Как выбрать значения из БД за интервал времени, в базе два столбца - дата и float значение(отношение одной валюты к другой)

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете передать Range в where

```
User.where({ created_at: (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight })
```